# Caption numbering not in sequential order when citing the captions with captioner in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, caption, bookdown

I am using captioner (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/captioner/vignettes/using_captioner.html) to create table captions in Rmarkdown - the main reason is because I am using huxtable for conditional formatting and exporting to word. This is the only I have found to have numbered captions.

I was trying to reference the captions but the caption number is not in sequential order when citing the captions but only if the table_nums(..., display="cite") is before the tables. I was trying to give the range of table numbers and it changed the number of the last table. I The number isn't changed if the r table_nums('third_cars_table',display = "cite") is put after the captions. Is there a way to make sure that table numbers remain in sequential order? I'd also be happy with a better solution for numbered captions.

Reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: bookdown::word_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(captioner)
library(huxtable)
library(knitr)
library(pander)
table_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Table")
fig_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Figure")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


## Description of tables
I am trying to put a description of tables 
and say that these results are shown table numbers ranging 
from the first table (`r table_nums('first_cars_table',display = "cite")`)
 to the last table (`r table_nums('third_cars_table',display = "cite")`)

```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,eval.after=TRUE}
tablecap1=cat(table_nums(name="first_cars_table",caption='First car table'))
kable((cars[1:5,]))

tablecap2=cat(table_nums(name="second_cars_table",caption='second car table'))
kable(cars[6:10,])

tablecap3=cat(table_nums(name="third_cars_table",caption='third car table'))
kable(cars[10:15,])
```
````

The results:[image]

Answer (score 0):

A (terrible) workaround is to manually give the number ordering using `display = FALSE`. For example, inserting the following at the start of the document will ensure `t1-t5` are sequentially numbered, no matter where the tables or first citations appear:

```
`r table_nums('t1', display = FALSE)`
`r table_nums('t2', display = FALSE)`
`r table_nums('t3', display = FALSE)`
`r table_nums('t4', display = FALSE)`
`r table_nums('t5', display = FALSE)`
```

I have not examined the `captioner` code but I expect that the document is read from top to bottom once and hence the numbering is stored in a first come, first served basis. Thus, I am not sure there are any other ways to get around this as it would involve some kind of pre-processing stage.